# Issue with Creation of new Instances becuase of unallocated External IP

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I tried creating some compute instances in us-central1-a and us-central1-b , but as soon as an instance is created , It gets terminated because , the compute engine service is not able to assign an external IP address . While the machine gets started an external IP gets assigned to it but soon after the IP get unassigned from the machine and its get halted.

PS:  there is no issue with the Quota limitation.

Comment: Flagged for closing as this was caused by a temporary issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try it again, it seems from the [post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gce-discussion/yRHBFXrM0ys) that there were some issue yesterday.

UPDATE: See [link](https://status.cloud.google.com/incident/compute/15051) also for additional information. This was a temporary issue and it is already solved.